# Getting point cloud from turtlebot?

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am using the turtlebot simulator in gazebo and I want to get its pointcloud data and send it in real time to a mapping program (gmapping maybe?). Where can I find the pointcloud data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239062/getting-point-cloud-from-turtlebot?/) by [Morefoam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27425/morefoam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Run a `rostopic list` and see if you can see `/scan` topic. If you can, then that's the topic into which pointcloud data is published.

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2016-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0